# Getting property values inside object using reflection doesn't work

Tags: c#

Trying to get into reflection and as a noob I don't understand why this isn't working.

```
foreach (var p in localStorageProfile.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    userprofile.Name = p.GetValue("name").ToString();
    userprofile.PhotoUrl = p.GetValue("photoUrl").ToString();
}
```

I used `ToString` because they should be strings

This is the exception

`System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type. at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)`

And the object as it comes from the client looks like this:

`{{"id":0,"name":"Mollie","photoUrl":"assets/images/portraits/1.png","imagePublicId":null...`
I wanna get properties inside the `object` type this way because I wanna get into reflection a little bit to get used to it. And this code should work

Comment: That looks like JSON. Exactly what Type is `localStorageProfile`?

Comment: You need to pass the object from which you want the property value, e.g. `p.GetValue(localStorageProfile)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that in the example you have provided the variable `localStorageProfile` is of type `string` and contains the JSON data.

This would mean that `localStorageProfile.GetType().GetProperties()` is equivalent to writing out `typeof(System.String).GetProperties()` which would ultimately return properties of the `System.String` class and not JSON values.

Usually you want to use the reflection methods `GetProperty()` and `GetProperties()` with class objects that actually contain useful property information.

An primitive example could be:

```
public class Profile
{
    public Profile() { }

    public Profile(int id, string name, string photoUrl)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.PhotoUrl = photoUrl;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }
}

// Creating a sample profile
var dollie = new Profile(1, "Dollie", "assets/images/portraits/2.png");

// Creating an empty profile
var copyOfDollie = new Profile();

// Filling the empty profile using reflection
copyOfDollie.Id = (int)typeof(Profile).GetProperty("Id").GetValue(dollie);
copyOfDollie.Name = (string)typeof(Profile).GetProperty("Name").GetValue(dollie);
copyOfDollie.PhotoUrl = (string)typeof(Profile).GetProperty("PhotoUrl").GetValue(dollie);
```

If you just intended to parse the JSON instead use the `JsonSerializer` class:

```
string json = @"{
                   ""Id""  : 0,
                   ""Name"": ""Mollie"",
                   ""PhotoUrl"": ""assets/images/portraits/1.png""
                }";

var mollie = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Profile>(json);
```

Comment: Did this way: `var profileData =_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items["localStorageProfile"];
                var profileDataDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserProfileDto>(profileData.ToString());` Thank you very much for the explanations